# Create random word using StringBuilder - P

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create 10 lines of 3 words using a string builder and random. Currently, I have two loops but not producing what I want.

```
 public String generateRandSentences() {

        }
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your method returns a single String. You might want to return a `List<String>` instead.

Comment: your variable names are misleading. `sentences`are certainly NOT sentences

Comment: you also want the number 15 not to be a constant... but the amount of elements

Comment: @Eran sorry, I want to set this to a textview.

Answer (score 1):

try to do it step by step you can replace these line

```
String rGenCharSet = sentences[rGen.nextInt(sentences.length)];
            strBuilder.append(rGenCharSet + " ");
```

to

```
int randomnumber =  rGen.nextInt(sentences.length);
String rGenCharSet = sentences[randomnumber];
strBuilder.append(rGenCharSet + " ");
```

and then try to print the string builder in output

Note that `println()` prints a string builder, as in:

```
System.out.println(sb);
```

because `sb.toString()` is called implicitly, as it is with any other object in a `println()` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It generates one line of 75 characters because a line separator is never inserted.  Try adding `strBuilder.append('\n')` after each sentence is generated as in:

```
public String generateRandSentences() {
    String[] sentences = {"mum", "can", "you", "get", "one", "bun", "for",
            "guy", "one", "for", "gus", "his", "old", "man", "who"};
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Random rGen = new Random();

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int words = 0; words < 15; words++) {
            String rGenCharSet = sentences[rGen.nextInt(sentences.length)];
            strBuilder.append(rGenCharSet + " ");
        }
        strBuilder.append('\n');
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}

TextView txtView1 = findViewById(R.id.txtview_vc_1);
txtView1.setText(generateRandSentences());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args){

generateRandSentences();

                                    }




public static void generateRandSentences() {
Random rGen = new Random();
String[] sentences = {"mum", "can", "you", "get", "one", "bun", "for","guy", "one", "for", "gus", "his", "old", "man", "who"};
int size = sentences.length;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for(int j = 0 ; j < 15 ; j++)
  {
    String str = sentences[rGen.nextInt(size)];
    strBuilder.append(str + " ");
  }
  System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());  
}


                                            }
      }
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will help current and future users.